# What is explanation of vars' addresses

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    struct S {};

    int main() {
      S s1, s2;
      char c1, c2;
      cout << (uintptr_t)&s1 << '\n' << (uintptr_t)&s2 << '\n' << (uintptr_t)&c1 << '\n' << (uintptr_t)&c2 << '\n';
    }
```

Example of output:

```
19920899
19920887
19920875
19920863
```

I would guess that each next var has bigger address and a difference of 1 byte, but instead the difference is 12 bytes and addresses are decreasing.

Comment: why did you expect that? As far as C++ is concerned the values of the adresses could be anything, they need not even be in any order

Comment: This is what I get when I run your code.
140735891964644
140735891964645
140735891964646
140735891964647

Comment: But, that's not guaranteed to be the output; as @463035818_is_not_a_number rightly commented.

Comment: Ok, why 12 bytes?

Comment: It is up to your compiler/implementation to decide padding, to decide what direction your stack grows, to decide whether debugging data should be embedded with your variables.  C++ makes no such demands regarding what this program would output.  _"why 12 bytes"_ would depend on the compiler you have chosen and the compiler flags used.

Comment: *looks at crystal ball* This is a debug build, and there is a particular pattern written in the bytes between them

Comment: I see, if @Drew Dormann create and answer, that should be an accepted answer.

Comment: 1. on x86 stack grows to smaller addresses. 2. It depends on compiler and it flags. gcc uses constitutive addresses, clang adds some padding (like msvc): https://godbolt.org/z/5fEKPoGbd

Comment: Visual studio debug builds adds sentinels between stack variables to detect buffer overflows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to your compiler/implementation to decide padding, to decide what direction your stack grows, to decide whether debugging data should be embedded with your variables.

C++ makes no such demands regarding what this program would output. "why 12 bytes" would depend on the compiler you have chosen, the target architecture,  and the compiler flags used.